# How to wrap API Endpoint with middleware

Tags: go

AM trying generate and appy the client credential accesstoken to wrap simple API endpoint. I got code that work well when all codes are in the main function. However, i woild like to have the API endpoint (/protected) outside the main function in a different directory together with the middleware. 
How do I do this, so that middleware apply to every request to the server?

my main function in the parent directory

```
func main() {
    log.Printf("Server started")

    router := sw.NewRouter()
    manager := manage.NewDefaultManager()
    manager.SetAuthorizeCodeTokenCfg(manage.DefaultAuthorizeCodeTokenCfg)

    manager.MustTokenStorage(store.NewMemoryTokenStore())

    clientStore := store.NewClientStore()
    manager.MapClientStorage(clientStore)

    srv := server.NewDefaultServer(manager)
    srv.SetAllowGetAccessRequest(true)
    srv.SetClientInfoHandler(server.ClientFormHandler)
    manager.SetRefreshTokenCfg(manage.DefaultRefreshTokenCfg)

    srv.SetInternalErrorHandler(func(err error) (re *errors.Response) {
        log.Println("Internal Error:", err.Error())
        return
    })

    srv.SetResponseErrorHandler(func(re *errors.Response) {
        log.Println("Response Error:", re.Error.Error())
    })

    router.HandleFunc("/oauth2/token", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        srv.HandleTokenRequest(w, r)
    })

    router.HandleFunc("/credentials", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        clientId := uuid.New().String()[:8]
        clientSecret := uuid.New().String()[:8]
        err := clientStore.Set(clientId, &models.Client{
            ID:     clientId,
            Secret: clientSecret,
            Domain: "http://localhost:9094",
        })
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err.Error())
        }

        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(map[string]string{"CLIENT_ID": clientId, "CLIENT_SECRET": clientSecret})
    })

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", router))
}


middleware API endpoint and router in a sub directory


func protecteduri(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("Hello, I'm protected"))
}

func validateToken(f http.HandlerFunc, srv *server.Server) http.HandlerFunc {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        _, err := srv.ValidationBearerToken(r)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
            return
        }

        f.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}


router

type Route struct {
    Name        string
    Method      string
    Pattern     string
    HandlerFunc http.HandlerFunc
}

type Routes []Route

func NewRouter() *mux.Router {
    router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    for _, route := range routes {
        var handler http.Handler
        handler = route.HandlerFunc
        handler = Logger(handler, route.Name)

        router.
            Methods(route.Method).
            Path(route.Pattern).
            Name(route.Name).
            Handler(handler)
    }

    return router
}

func Index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello World!")
}

var routes = Routes{
    {
        "Index",
        "GET",
        "/",
        Index,
    },

    {
        "protecteduri",
        strings.ToUpper("Get"),
        "/protected",
        protecteduri,
    },

    {
        "AccessTokenRequest",
        strings.ToUpper("Post"),
        "/oauth2/token",
        AccessTokenRequest,
    },
}
```

Normally i add middleware in the router file as

hadler = middleware(handler)

and it apply to all the incoming request but in this case it does not
work.

The full working code is this

```
func main() {
   manager := manage.NewDefaultManager()
   manager.SetAuthorizeCodeTokenCfg(manage.DefaultAuthorizeCodeTokenCfg)

   // token memory store
   manager.MustTokenStorage(store.NewMemoryTokenStore())

   // client memory store
   clientStore := store.NewClientStore()

   manager.MapClientStorage(clientStore)

   srv := server.NewDefaultServer(manager)
   srv.SetAllowGetAccessRequest(true)
   srv.SetClientInfoHandler(server.ClientFormHandler)
   manager.SetRefreshTokenCfg(manage.DefaultRefreshTokenCfg)

   srv.SetInternalErrorHandler(func(err error) (re *errors.Response) {
      log.Println("Internal Error:", err.Error())
      return
   })

   srv.SetResponseErrorHandler(func(re *errors.Response) {
      log.Println("Response Error:", re.Error.Error())
   })

   http.HandleFunc("/oauth2/token", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
      srv.HandleTokenRequest(w, r)
   })

   http.HandleFunc("/credentials", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
      clientId := uuid.New().String()[:8]
      clientSecret := uuid.New().String()[:8]
      err := clientStore.Set(clientId, &models.Client{
         ID:     clientId,
         Secret: clientSecret,
         Domain: "http://localhost:9094",
      })
      if err != nil {
         fmt.Println(err.Error())
      }

      w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
      json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(map[string]string{"CLIENT_ID": clientId, "CLIENT_SECRET": clientSecret})
   })

   http.HandleFunc("/protected", validateToken(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
      w.Write([]byte("Hello, I'm protected"))
   }, srv))

   log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":9096", nil))
}

//main function end here
//middleware function below

func validateToken(f http.HandlerFunc, srv *server.Server) http.HandlerFunc {
   return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
      _, err := srv.ValidationBearerToken(r)
      if err != nil {
         http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
         return
      }

      f.ServeHTTP(w, r)
   })
}
```

As you can see the accesstoken to request this handle function http.HandleFunc("/protected"... below is validated using the middleware function "validateToken".

```
http.HandleFunc("/protected", validateToken(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
      w.Write([]byte("Hello, I'm protected"))
   }, srv))
```

What i want to do is to rewrite the main function by moving the route handle function (http.HandleFunc("/protected"...) outside the main function and still the the accesstoken get validated when i send request to the (http.HandleFunc("/protected", validateToken(...) function using the routes defined above. In the ealier code, it works but the token to the handlefunction

```
func protecteduri(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("Hello, I'm protected"))
}
```

is not validated.

i will be adding more handle function and do not want to put all of them in the main function.

```
http.HandleFunc("/protected", validateToken(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
      w.Write([]byte("Hello, I'm protected"))
   }, srv))
```

Comment: Hiya!  It's a bit tough to tell what exactly you're asking here.  If it's just "how do I access functions in a package that's in a subdirectory, then it'd be something like making sure "package protected" is in your subdir's source file and doing an "import nameofmainpackage.protected" and then using protected.protecteduri in the Routes{}.  But it's a bit unclear.

Comment: "but in this case it does not work." Why not?

Comment: Also the code is not complete. Please share complete code

Comment: what i mean by it does not work means that when a request is sent to access the "protecteduri" function, the accesstoken is not validated as it was in the working  function main()